# Como ordenar um um vetor utilizando dois atributos?

Tags: c++, classificação, vector, atributos

Vamos lá... tenho uma classe Aluno, que contem os atributos **nome**, **idCurso** e **situacao**. Tenho também um vector que armazena vários objetos do tipo Aluno.
Tenho também um método **ordenaPorCurso()** que me retorna um vector ordenado pelo curso.
Segue o método:

```
    vector<Aluno> ordenaPorCurso(Vector<Aluno> lista){
         for(int i = 0 ; i < lista.size() ; i++){
            for(int j = i ; j < lista.size() ; j++){

                if(lista[i].getCurso() >= lista[j].getCurso()){

                    Aluno temp = lista[j];
                    lista[j] = lista[i];
                    lista[i] = temp;

                }
            }
        }return lista;
```

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Preciso criar um método que ordene por Curso **E** Nome e estou travado. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Grato.

Comment: Faz um overload do operador < dizendo como você quer que instâncias da classe Aluno devem ser ordenadas. Depois, você pode usar a função sort para ordenar o seu vetor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer a ordenação por dois campos você deve comparar nesta ordem:

1. se o primeiro campo de um elemento é **maior** que o do outro elemento;
2. se o primeiro campo de um elemento é **igual** ao do outro elemento **e** o segundo campo é **maior ou igual** ao do outro elemento;

Assim sendo, a comparação entre os dois elementos ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
if ((lista[i].getCurso()  > lista[j].getCurso()) ||
    (lista[i].getCurso() == lista[j].getCurso()  && lista[i].getNome() >= lista[j].getNome())) {
```

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado!
E se fosse a comparação entre três elementos? Como ficaria?

Comment: Para três elementos basta comparar o terceiro campo quando o primeiro e o segundo forem iguais. O código fica meio complicado para fazer isso tudo em um único `if`, então sugiro separar em mais de uma operação ou implementar operadores de comparação. Se quiser o código faça uma pergunta apropriada que eu colocarei o código lá.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/440878/como-ordenar-um-um-vetor-utilizando-tr%c3%aas-atributos