# Como ordenar um um vetor utilizando três atributos?

Tags: c++, classificação, vector, atributos

Vamos lá... tenho uma classe Aluno, que contem os atributos **nome, idCurso e situacao**. Tenho também um vector que armazena vários objetos do tipo Aluno. Tenho também um método **ordenaPorCursoENome()** que me retorna um vector ordenado pelo curso e nome. Segue o método:

```
vector<Aluno> ordenaPorCursoENome(Vector<Aluno> lista){
     for(int i = 0 ; i < lista.size() ; i++){
        for(int j = i ; j < lista.size() ; j++){

            if ((lista[i].getCurso()  > lista[j].getCurso()) ||
(lista[i].getCurso() == lista[j].getCurso()  && lista[i].getNome() >= lista[j].getNome())) {

                Aluno temp = lista[j];
                lista[j] = lista[i];
                lista[i] = temp;

            }
        }
    }return lista;
```

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: Preciso criar um método que ordene por **Curso, Nome e Situacão** e estou travado. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visto que você já perguntou como fazer para adicionar o segundo campo anteriormente [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/439343/como-ordenar-um-um-vetor-utilizando-dois-atributos), acredito que seja melhor explicar como funciona a comparação de dois campos ou mais. Dessa forma você poderá incluir quantos quiser.

Estou considerando que você saiba como funciona o *bubble sort*, que é o algoritmo de ordenação implementado na função que você postou junto com a pergunta.

Quando você quer comparar dois objetos baseado em apenas uma propriedade, basta verificar se a primeira propriedade do objeto `a` é maior ou igual à primeira propriedade do objeto `b` e fazer a troca em caso positivo. Exemplo:

```cpp
if (a.primeira() >= b.primeira()) {
    // troca ordem
}
```

Quando você tem uma segunda propriedade e precisa fazer a ordenação, você deve primeiro comparar se a primeira propriedade do objeto `a` é **maior** que a mesma propriedade do objeto `b` e, se for verdade, deve fazer troca. Caso não seja verdade, você deve em seguida verificar se a primeira propriedade do objeto `a` é **igual** a mesma propriedade do objeto `b` **E** se a segunda propriedade do objeto `a` é **maior ou igual** à mesma propriedade do objeto `b`. Exemplo:

```cpp
if ((a.primeira()  > b.primeira()) ||
    (a.primeira() == b.primeira() && a.segunda() >= b.segunda())) {
    // troca ordem
}
```

Para adicionar a terceira propriedade basta fazer a mesma coisa que fizemos para a adicionar a segunda: ao comparar a segunda propriedade faça a troca se a segunda for **maior** ou se a segunda for **igual** e a terceira for **maior ou igual**. Exemplo:

```cpp
if ((a.primeira()  > b.primeira()) ||
    (a.primeira() == b.primeira() && a.segunda()  > b.segunda())) {
    (a.primeira() == b.primeira() && a.segunda() == b.segunda() && a.terceira() >= b.terceira())) {
    // troca ordem
}
```

Até aqui o código ainda está legível, mas caso você tenha a intenção de adicionar várias outras propriedades recomendo você pensar em um algoritmo comparação mais legível.

Enfim, sua funcão `ordenaPorCursoENomeESituacao()` ficaria da seguinte forma:

```cpp
vector<Aluno> ordenaPorCursoENomeESituacao(vector<Aluno> lista){
     for(int i = 0 ; i < lista.size() ; i++){
        for(int j = i ; j < lista.size() ; j++){

            if ((lista[i].getCurso()  > lista[j].getCurso()) ||
                (lista[i].getCurso() == lista[j].getCurso()  && lista[i].getNome()  > lista[j].getNome()) ||
                (lista[i].getCurso() == lista[j].getCurso()  && lista[i].getNome() == lista[j].getNome()  && lista[i].getSituacao() >= lista[j].getSituacao())) {

                Aluno temp = lista[j];
                lista[j] = lista[i];
                lista[i] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
     return lista;
}
```